# Not Exists isn't working

Tags: oracle, inner-join, not-exists

**A little explanation:**

`Ids` is the table that makes the relation between students and disciplines.

`Matrix` is the table that have all the curriculum of all courses.

So, I'm trying to get the disciplines that still are **NOT** linked with the student, in other words, I want to get all the remaining disciplines.

Here's my code for while:

```
SELECT d.cod_disc, cod_course
FROM students s
JOIN ids i ON s.mat_alu = i.mat_alu
JOIN disciplines d ON i.cod_disc = d.cod_disc
WHERE s.mat_alu = 78839
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM matrix m
                        WHERE m.cod_disc = d.cod_disc);
```

How can I make it work? It's returning nothing.

**EDIT:**

**First query:** -- The main `SELECT`

```
COD_DISC     COD_COURSE
--------     ----------
335          13
3824         13
3831         13
3835         13
6235         13
6237         13
```

`SELECT cod_disc, cod_course * FROM matrix WHERE cod_course = 13` -- 13 is the course.id of that student.

```
COD_DISC     COD_COURSE
--------     ----------
3824         13
3825         13
3826         13
3827         13
3828         13
3829         13
3830         13
3831         13
3832         13
3833         13
3834         13
3835         13
```

So, in my query I want to return almost all values less (3824, 3831 and 3835) because the student is already linked.

Comment: Believe me. It's working the way it's supposed to. Apparently EVERY `cod_disc` from disciplines has at least 1 matching row in `matrix`. Given your additional condition on `mat_alu`, of course.

Comment: @ConsiderMe I added some more info, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add another condition to your inner query:

```
SELECT d.cod_disc, cod_course
FROM students s
JOIN ids i ON s.mat_alu = i.mat_alu
JOIN disciplines d ON i.cod_disc = d.cod_disc
WHERE s.mat_alu = 78839
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM matrix m
                        WHERE m.cod_disc = d.cod_disc
                        and m.cod_course = d.cod_course);
```

Otherwise, it will match any other cod_course that has that cod_disc.